# How does Windows locate me while my PC does not have GPS?

Tags: geolocation, gps

When I go to Google Maps in browser and press the 'Show Your Location' button, it shows exactly where I am.

I was wondering how is that possible without GPS.

Comment: If it's *exactly* where you're at, then Google may know your exact location through other devices. Do you have an Android phone logged into the Google account you may be using on the PC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are databases with visible wireless LANs and their coordinates - both commercial and free (like [wigle.net](https://wigle.net)). If there are multiple WLANs visible, one could triangulate using field intensity and improve geolocation accuracy.

A different approach would be to make educated guesses using your IP address. A service demonstrating that is [this](https://www.iplocation.net) one.

Comment: The browser has no ability to query the Wifi SSIDs nor their RSSIs to perform triangulation. Only the IP address, which is not exact, or some other data which Google has about the user.

Comment: @DanielF counterexample: e.g. JavaScript in Safari browser **can** use an official [API](https://tinyurl.com/24hfvwer) which indeed does employ SSIDs, Bluetooth, and other means for geolocation.

Comment: Ah, ok TIL. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: The browser ask the system about a location, and it's using the Wifi when available. You can try with a computer connected in ethernet. When the wifi is disabled, it have a low accuracy (using IP location) but when you have the wifi enabled, then it's way more accurate.